# Before filter in routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need a `before filter` on my route, for my `RESTful` controller:

Here's what I have:

```
Route::controller('gateway', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'GatewayController'));
```

I get the error:

```
'ErrorException' with message 'Array to string conversion'
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you sure error is because of the filter?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but you may find you can't do what you're attempting to on a `Route::controller` call - I think it has to be `Route::controller(string $uriPrefix, string $controllerFQCN)`. You can get over this by either wrapping that in a [`Route::group()`](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups) or by setting up your filters in your [controller's constructor](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters) - you only really want CSRF checks on POST requests anyway, so it may be worth doing it in the controller's constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll wrap it. And thanks for the advice, my gateway is just for POSTs anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: fyi, you can also use the `Route::when` to restrict the filter only to post requests. Something like: `Route::when('gateway/*', 'csrf', array('post'));`

Comment: Hmm, the when stuff doesnt appear to work, just tried putting a get in the controller and requiring a post on the route, still works...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
// Controller : GatewayController
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter( 'csrf', array( 'on' => array( 'post' ) ) );
}
```

Put this `__construct()` method inside your `RESTful` Controller. Here `'on' => array( 'post' )` is used to indicate that, thew filter should be done only on `POST` requests and you may add other `HTTP` methods here. The signature of `controller` method in `Router` class is as follows:

```
public function controller($uri, $controller, $names = array()) { ... }
```

In this case the second argument must be `String` instead of an `Array`. In your question the given example is this:

```
Route::controller('gateway', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'GatewayController'));
```

Here, the second argument is an `Array` so the error `'ErrorException' with message 'Array to string conversion'` occurs.

You may also put the `__construct()` method inside your `BaseController` so you don't have to use it in every controller. Alternatively you may use a `group` as well (if you have more than one routes), like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){
    Route::controller('gateway', 'GatewayController');  
});
```